# An error occured while Parsing an XML document. "The element type "p" must be terminated"

Tags: xml, parsing, document

THIS HAS BEEN TAKEN CARE OF.  THanks! :)

My boss is on vacation and a client called with an issue on their cart (ColdFusion) site.  This is beyond my knowledge (I'm lightly experienced with PHP).

After you go through the process of adding a product to the cart, entering your personal info, you get a page that asks you to select a password - once you try to go forward from there you receive the error.

```
An error occured while Parsing an XML document.

The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "
".

Resources:
Enable Robust Exception Information to provide greater detail about the source of errors. In the Administrator, click Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings, and select the Robust Exception Information option.
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.218 Safari/535.1
Remote Address      67.238.189.18
Referrer    http://www.innovate4independence.com/checkout_saveInfo.cfm
Date/Time   06-Sep-11 12:44 PM
```

I'd like to try to help this client if at all possible.  I've just run it through a validator and am going to look at the results now.

Comment: Ok... ? I have no idea what that means.  Again, I didn't build this cart, just seeing if it is indeed something as simple as an unclosed P tag, if I can resolve this.  I'm just trying to be helpful.

Comment: In HTML `<p>` does not need to be closed while it does in XML (and therefor XHTML). See nobsids answer for how to get the browser to treat it as "normal HTML".

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere your application is parsing an XML file where there is a `<p>` tag which is not closed by an appropriate `</p>` tag.

You should be more clear in your question:

- what to you mean with *I've just run it through a validator*: **it**?
- what happens after the password input?
- do you know which XML file/stream is generating the error?

Comment: I've run IT - the PAGE in question to see if it found any unclosed tags

After I input a password thats when I get the error page in question

I do not know which SML file/stream is generating the error, like I said, I didn't write this cart application, I do not code in ColdFusion.

Comment: Ok I thought that the error was generated by the application not the browser: is this the case? Where is the error generated?

Comment: Actually, after digging around I've been told the only XML being used in this cart/site comes from the point where the cart interacts with the shipper (which I believe is UPS) - so it may not be from 'us' - esp since the cart was working before.  Hmmm.  Anyhow... thanks for the replies.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the document is being served as application/xhtml+xml, meaning the browser will parse it as an XML document. You should be able to fix the issue by either making sure the document is valid ( closing the p tag ), or serve the page as application/html

Comment: So I'm on the search for an unclosed P tag.  I did a search of all the obvious files (the file itself, any includes) and found no starting P's with out a closing.  But who ever coded this has text that is not wrapped in any tags (no p tag at all) could that also be an issue?

Also could the error be something being passed forward from the previous (create a password) page?  (Sorry, I am NOT a programmer- I hack WordPress, LOL)

Comment: The error should be different if the p tag is excluded altogether, something like `document does not allow "text" here`. I believe it is still possible to view the source of that page when such an error occurs. If you can replicate the issue and view the source it might give you a better clue where the invalid markup is coming from.